# C# Get 1 directory down

Tags: c#

I've tried several ways to achieve this but here goes...

I have the following directory:

c:\one\two\three

I need to get to this directory:

c:\one\two

Not always is it just 3 directories, it could be like this:

c:\one\two\three\four\five

In which I need:

c:\one\two\three\four

Always one directory down...

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
Eroc

Comment: Maybe it's what I have that's causing the issue.

Comment: I am trying to get the parent of this: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Path.GetDirectoryName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

Comment: this worked if I did this: Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))  I'm not sure if that is correct though... seems a little excessive

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) property of `DirectoryInfo` or the static [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) method:

```
DirectoryInfo parent = Directory.GetParent(@"c:\one\two\three\four\five");
Console.WriteLine(parent.Name);
```

Comment: Remember to check if parent is null (if your input directory is root).

Comment: Actually, you should use parent.FullName to get the "c:\one\two\three\four" string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Path.Combine(directoryName, "..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you're just interested in the startup path you can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or Application.StartupPath (WinForms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Directory.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) method, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetParent(@"c:\one\two\three\four\five").FullName);
```

Result =>

```
c:\one\two\three\four
```

Comment: Remember to check if parent is null (if your input directory is root).